# Copy values instead of formulas

Tags: excel, vba

Could someone help me tweak this slightly so it copies and pastes just the values to the cells and not the formulas?

```
Set copyRange = wsInfoFrom.Range("A1:A" & lastrow) 
copyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy wsInfoTo.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
Worksheets("View").Activate
```

Regards,
Mils

Comment: Thanks Gary's Student i'm new to this site if you didn't guess :)

Comment: You miight looking for this? - "https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-pastespecial-method-excel"

Comment: I was hoping that you would be able to use `... .Value = ... .Value` but the `.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)` complicates things, so the answers by Duc Anh Nguyen (using `wsInfoFrom` and `wsInfoTo` instead of `ActiveSheet`) and by Ricardo Rodrigues are probably the easiest to implement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fist you select the source range
Then you select the target range
Set copy to sc and pastespecial to target range and there you go :D

```
Set copyRange = ActiveSheet.Range("A1:A" & lastrow)
copyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
ActiveSheet.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Worksheets("View").Activate
```

Comment: This is what I needed but I had to adapt it to pull the data from a different Sheet instead of the Active sheet. Many Thanks Mils

Comment: :D, forgot to change back the sheet. I do not have the same workbook so that I have to change the variable to the activesheet. Great to hear that work. And please have a look at the link at the comment for technical detail.

Answer (score 3):

Something like this should work

```
Sheets("Sheet1").Columns(1).Copy
Sheets("Sheet2").Columns(2).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```

Don't have excel available to me at the moment but I believe you'd use PasteSpecial like this in your example:

```
wsInfoTo.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```

Comment: In my opinion, this topic would like to copy the upper rows value to the lower rows. not from column A to column B. ;) But this is close to the answer anw